# Why MAT_DATE_LOCALE does not apply language?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I use this code to set language for MAT_DATEPICKER element:

```
import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from "@angular/material";

@Component({
  selector: "oputax-report",
  providers: [{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: "fr-FR" }]
})
```

But there is not effect, it is still in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use instance of DateAdapter for setting locale like below.

```
this._adapter.setLocale('fr');
```

you can checkout this working code [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c3j1vb).

Comment: is there a global adapter? still... your answer did not work for me. it still in english.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in stackblitz